# Closure for setInterval function in javascript

Tags: javascript, closures, setinterval

How to use `setInterval` without using global variables? I'd prefer to wrap all variables of function invoked by setInerval in some kind of closure, like so:

```
var wrap = function (f){
 var local1, local2, ...;
 return function () { return f(); }
}
```

This doesn't work, but the idea is that I'd pass `wrap(f)` instead of `f` to `setInterval`, so that locals for `f` are nicely wrapped and don't pollute the global scope.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

javascript don't have dynamic binding.(except this keyword)

use anonymous function can archive your idea. (it called closure)

```
var fnc = function(){
    var local1, local2;

    return function(){
         // using local1, local2
    }
};

setInterval(fnc, 1000);
```

Comment: If I have two functions I use in setInterval calls, there's no other way to exchange data between them, than using global variables?

Comment: @user1367401 Yes and no. The variables will need to be declared in an outer scope for both functions to have them in their scope, but that doesn't have to be the global scope. You can define all of them within the same closure -- [Revealing Module Pattern](http://addyosmani.com/resources/essentialjsdesignpatterns/book/#revealingmodulepatternjavascript).

Answer (score 2):

I assume you're looking for something like this...

```
var wrap = function (f){
    var locals = Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments, 1);
    return function () { f.apply(this, locals); }
};


function logger_func() {
    console.log.apply(console, arguments);
}

for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    setTimeout( wrap(logger_func, i, "foo_" + i), // <-- wrapping i
                i * 1000 );
}
```

---

Note that modern environments let you pass extra arguments to `setTimeout`...

```
for (var i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
    setTimeout(logger_func, i * 1000, i, "foo_" + i);
}
```