# How to deal with setTimeout in setInterval within a closure

Tags: javascript, closures, settimeout

```
function doSth(fn) {
  // only code here
}

const fn = doSth(()=>{
  console.log('hello world');
})

setInterval(() => {
  fn()
},10)
```

This function requires a output of "hello world" one time per second, I was trying to use something like function throttle inside the closure but it didn't work as I expected:

```
  function doSth(fn) {

    return function () {
      clearTimeout(fn.tid)
      fn.tid = setTimeout(function () {
        fn()
      },1000)
    }
  }

  const fn = doSth(()=>{
    console.log('hello world');
  })

  setInterval(() => {
    fn()
  },10)
```

I expected that There will be a setTimeout function every 1 second , and the extra call will be canceled , but it's seems so confused. Is it because of the closure inside the doSth function or the way I use the setTimeout ?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Closure for setInterval function in javascript](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11800436/closure-for-setinterval-function-in-javascript)

Comment: I thinks question was already solved by [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/11800572/5372008)

Comment: I think they are not the same

Comment: That question shows you how to use the `setInterval` within a closure. Therefore, now you can deal with the `setTimeout` based on that structure. You seem to be asking for someone to write some code for you. Stack Overflow is a question and answer site, not a code-writing service. Please read about [How to Ask a Question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) to learn how to write effective questions.

Comment: I never meant to have someone write codes for me. After reading the info you gave me, I still don't know how to deal the the limit of outputs. thanks

Comment: did you see that is something more specific I recommend you to update your question and put that u follow the link that I send you. that will help us to find the right answer for your question.

Comment: I posted a possible answer to your question ok let me know if that is what you need...

Comment: I updated the answer with a `setTimeout` inside of the `setInterval`

Comment: What behavior are you actually seeing?  Just from eye-balling the code, it seems like your `setInterval` calls `fn()` every 10ms.  `fn()` clears the previous timeout and then sets a `setTimeout` to execute 1000ms later.  But after only 10ms, `setInterval` will call `fn()` again which will clear the current `setTimeout` 990ms before it triggers.  So no `setTimeout` calls will actually occur, because they are always cleared before they have a chance to execute.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `setTimeout` will not solve your problem. It's just logical. What `setTimeout` does is delay execution of something. So if you have a `setInterval` 100 times per second (every 10 milliseconds) and you call `setTimeout` inside it all you are doing is call `setTimeout` 100 times per second which will still print `hello world` 100 times per second:

```
 100 times per second            100 times per second

 setInterval
 setInterval ╲
 setInterval ╲╲
      .      ╲╲╲    1 second later
      .       ╲╲╲
      .        ╲╲╲
                ╲╲╲______________ setTimeout
                 ╲╲______________ setTimeout
                  ╲______________ setTimeout
                                      .
                                      .
```

The solution is to count how many time you've been called and print `hello world` every 100 times `setInterval` calls your function. Let's start with the most simple way to do this: global variables:

```
var counter = 0;

function doSth(fn) {
  counter ++;
  if (counter >= 100) { // once per second
    counter = 0;
    fn();
  }
}
```

This works, however we've introduced a global variable which is ugly. Fortunately we know that the `setInterval` will not be calling our function directly. Instead it expects our function to return another function which it will call:

```
const fn = doSth(...);
```

Which means we need to write our function like this:

```
var counter = 0;

function doSth(fn) {  // <──┐
  return function(){  // <──┴─ oh look, a closure!
    counter ++;
    if (counter >= 100) { // once per second
      counter = 0;
      fn();
    }
  }
}
```

This is very fortunate because closures are a mechanism that allows functions to share local variables. Basically it makes local variables behave a bit like global variables but does not pollute the global namespace. Now we can simply move the global variable into the closure:

```
function doSth(fn) {

  var counter = 0;

  return function(){
    counter ++;
    if (counter >= 100) { // once per second
      counter = 0;
      fn();
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If I understand correctly, it would seem that you have to move the setInterval into the doSth(fn) function.

```
function doSth(fn) {
  setInterval(() => {
    fn();
    }, 10)
}

const fn = doSth(() => {
    console.log('hello world');
})
```

Comment: unfortunately,It can't work, and the it only allows me to write code inside the "doSth" function

Comment: Ok, I retested with your code and I removed  **clearTimeout(fn.tid)** from you "doSth" and it seems to work.

Comment: However, it requires one output per second, the setInterval function made it one output in every 10 millisecond

Answer (score 0):

If your question is:

> I expected that There will be a `setTimeout` function **every 1 second**

This is the answer. Now how it works? well `setInterval` and `setTimeout` essentially try to do the same thing, but for your case `setInterval` method will be more accurate than `setTimeout`. why? because `setTimeout` waits 1000ms, runs the closure and then sets another timeout. So that **wait period** is actually a bit more than `1000ms` (or a lot more if your function takes a long time to execute).

Since JavaScript isn't a multi-threaded language, `setInterval` will also delay, which means that - if there are other parts of the script running - the interval will have to wait for that to finish.
Check this example I made for you.

**UPDATE** I put the `setTimeout`inside the `setInterval` please take a look.

```js
var speed = 1000; // One second
var start = +new Date;
var icounter = 0;
var tcounter = 0;
var fnLabel = '<td>fn</td><td>';
var setIntervalLabel = '<td>setInterval</td><td>';
var etdtd = '</td><td>';
var i = document.querySelector('#i');
var t = document.querySelector('#t');

setInterval(() => {
  fn();
  var time = (new Date - start) / 1000;
  var avg = tcounter++/ time;
  t.innerHTML = setIntervalLabel + tcounter + etdtd + time.toFixed(3) + etdtd + avg.toFixed(6) + etdtd + '</td>';
}, 10)

const fn = doSth(() => {
  var time = (new Date - start) / 1000;
  var avg = icounter++/ time;
  i.innerHTML = fnLabel + icounter + etdtd + time.toFixed(3) + etdtd + avg.toFixed(6) + etdtd + 'Hello ' + icounter + '</td>';
});

function doSth(fn) {
  var counter = 0;
  return function() {
    counter++;
    if (counter > 99) { // once per second
      counter = 0;
      fn();
    }
  }
}
```

```css
table,
th,
td {
  border: 1px solid black
}

th,
td {
  padding: .2em .4em .3em
}

th {
  font-weight: bold;
  background-color: #89C
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <th>type</th>
    <th>calls</th>
    <th>seconds</th>
    <th>average calls/second</th>
    <th>Say Hello world!</th>
  </tr>
  <tr id="i">
    <td>fn</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
  <tr id="t">
    <td>setIntervalLabel</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td>0</td>
    <td></td>
  </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I know that the execution time for setTimeout is not 100 percent accurate. What if I want to use setTimeout inside the setInterval, it seems that the first time of the execution is the setTimeout ,and then the frequency became the setInterval. How can I control the execution time inside the setInterval

Comment: It depends on the implementation. If you have a single `setTimeout` inside a `setInterval`, the interval will call a `setTimeout` after one second the the setTimeout will wait one second to execute the `Hello` and but also another seTimeout will be called by the  `setInterval`

Comment: If this is answer is ok for you please make it as answered to close the question.

Comment: the question below is what i am looking for, anyway thanks you a lot