# How can I make sure that my variable does not change inside the setInterval

Tags: javascript

I want to change the scrollLeft of a div on time,

let's make it simple :

```
var initialValue = $('#myDiv').scrollLeft();
var x = setInterval(function() {
$('#myDiv').scrollLeft("#some value calculated depending on initialValue")
}, 10)
```

the problem is the initialValue changes over time, the same problem remains when i put it inside the setInterval. How can I make sure that my initialValue variable does not change inside the setInterval ?

Comment: Likel dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11800436/closure-for-setinterval-function-in-javascript

Comment: I want the value to be calculated based on the initial value of initialValue, i did not understand the answer of link you posted

Comment: Which is why I did not hammerclose this as a duplicate

Answer (score 0):

Just use the scrollWidth property directly thus:

*Note: if you want to start at a particular scroll point, simply set `el.scrollWidth` to that starting value*

```js
var el = document.querySelector('#myDiv');
var step = (el.scrollWidth - el.scrollLeft)/10;
var x = setInterval(function() {
  el.scrollLeft += step;
  if(el.scrollLeft >= el.scrollWidth - el.clientWidth) clearInterval(x);
}, 100);
```

```css
#myDiv {
  border: 1px solid black;
  width: 250px;
  margin-bottom: 12px;
  overflow-x: scroll;
}
```

```html
<div id="myDiv">
  ABCDEFGHIJKLMOPQRSTUVWXYZABCDEFGHIJKLMOPQRSTUVWXYZ
</div>
```

Comment: thank you for your answer but what if you want the scroll left step to be depending on the initial starting point value? you gonna notice that the step is changing over time because your setInterval is changing your scroll left and thus is changing your step

Comment: i want for instance step = (scrollLeft_start_point_value - scrollLeft_end_point_value) / 10

Comment: I've updated the snippet to include your algorithm. I'm not sure I understand you hang up here. it does exactly what you want.